# How to use subclass function in self class

Tags: javascript, subclass, mixins, polymer-2.x

I'm using polymer 2 and I'm using mixin for behaviors. In my behavior sub-class, I could not use the method of the same sub-class. How can I do that?
Here is my code:

```
const Generic = (subclass) => class extends subclass
{
constructor ()
{
  super();
}

_arrayIntersect (a, b)
{
let bigArray = a.length > b.length ? a : b, common = [];

bigArray.forEach(function (elm) {

  if(a.indexOf(elm) !== -1 && b.indexOf(elm) !== -1)
  {
    common.push(elm);
  }
});

return common;
}

_inArray (needle, haystack)
{
  let length = haystack.length;
  for(let i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    if(haystack[i] === needle) return true;
  }
return false;
}

 bodyClick ()
 {
   el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
     // How to use `_arrayIntersect` and `_inArray` from here
     // this._inArray(needle, haystack) getting undefined message
   });
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *`this`* object inside click event indicates the clicked element instead of the class instance. To invoke super/sub class method you can assign the *`this`* object to a var, something like the following way:

```
bodyClick ()
{
   let self = this;
   el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
       let isExist = self._inArray(needle, haystack);
   });
}
```